# Need help to get the bodycontent using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have page i want replace body content with some second page body content.From the second page response text how to i will get the body content to replace the existing body content.

please help to me do this.

Thanks ,
In advance,
Raja.

Comment: currently i am doing some ajax call and updating the second page content.But while enabling html5 caching i want to mention the page url which needs to be cached that should in the manifest file.In my case ajax calls having dynamic parameters.I cant mention in the manifest file.In ajax call i will get only corresponding content which i need to replace. I have page url for  that second page there i will get full page content.That page only i need to get the body content and need to replace the existing page body.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `load()` function will do the trick:

```
$(function(){
    $("#something").load("/path/to/page2.php body");
});
```

Where `#something` is a jQuery selector of the element you want the data to load into, `/path/to/page2.php` is a relative URL to the page you want to load and `body` is the element on the page you want to load into the element. Information on how to use the function is available from [load at jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load).

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

```
$(body)[0]
```

But why are you doing this, rather than just replacing the content ( in a div with a class )

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').html('your new content goes here')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well with jquery you could do something like this:

```
  $('body').load('otherpage.html body');
```

This would clear the body of your html and load the body from otherpage.html

Comment: You don't need the `.html('')` in there. `load` replaces the content anyway: `$('body').load('otherpage.html body');`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you well, but if all you are trying to do is to set a page body element with the response you have got from ajax, then that should work:

```
document.body.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```